# How to identify writeable/partitioned views?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Assuming all the necessary prerequisite requirements are met, Sql Server will make partitioned views writable. How can I identify what views are in this state? A followup question would be- does the engine make this determination at the time the view is created and store it as an attribute of the view or is it determined dynamically?

If the latter, I would assume there is no way to verify correct operation without writing to the view. Is this correct?